# how to use form URL inside CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code :-

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>login/process" method="post" name="process">
    <h2>User Login</h2>
    <br />
    <?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?>            
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name='username' id='username' size="25" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id='password' size="25" /><br />                         
    <input type="Submit" value="Login" />         
</form>
```

But it not works.

when i remove this link

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>login/process" method="post" name="process">
```

after that it works.

Now my Question is how to use form URL inside CodeIgniter.

I know we can also do somehting like that :

```
<?=form_open('main/index/')?>
```

but I do not want to change my code right now.

Comment: you can not use <form action=""> tag in codigniter.you have to use <?php  echo form_open('admin/login/process');?> otherwise the form will not be submitted.

Comment: :) ,have u solved issue?

Comment: yes actually last time i forget to include   <?php  $this->load->helper('form'); ?> yes it works.

Comment: can u please tell me which form tag you used?

Comment: this one <?php  echo form_open('login/process');?>

Comment: i think my answer somewhere help you.. accept the answer.

Comment: well, One thing I want to know when last time I use this tag it does not works actually last time I added helper in the controller, but this time I add helper in view page and it works suddenly, Do u know why this happens ?

Comment: cause form_open is the method of  $this->load->helper('form'); form class .so without creating the instance of form class you can not use the form_open.

Comment: yes, but i can also create the instance from the controller, so why it does not works in case of controller. Right now i am doing something like this http://pastebin.com/FswvbeL6

Comment: the procedure you are following is fine,may be there is any other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not use  in codeigniter.Instead of that Use this:

```
<?php  echo form_open('admin/login/chk_admin');?>
    <h2>User Login</h2>
    <br />
    <?php if(! is_null($msg)) echo $msg;?>            
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" name='username' id='username' size="25" /><br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id='password' size="25" /><br />                         
    <input type="Submit" value="Login" />         
</form>
```